# remove black border from inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `PopupWindow`, which is working fine, but the problem is after inflating the layout view that is shown with black border.

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_window_menu_layout, null);
popupWindow.setContentView(view);
```

*pop_up_window_menu_layout.xml:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/solid_white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_sliding_list" />
```

I've tried to remove border by using `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`, but problem is still same.

Can anyone tell me how to remove unwanted black border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any border around my popup windows, but I do set them up slightly different than you. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

popup_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/main_view"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_popup"
        android:text="Popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_text"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    View popupView;
    Button btnPopup;
    Button btnClose;
    PopupWindow popupWindow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_view, null);
        btnClose = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
        btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_popup) {
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_view), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 200);
            //popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnPopup, 10, 10);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_close) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello mpkuth, can you please add backgorund color in ur parent layout inside "popup_view.xml" to android:background="#f5f5f5" and check if still u r not getting any border.as if background is drak or default color then its not easily noticable. with light background , u can find it out very easily.

Comment: @mann Updated my answer with that background and a screenshot. I see the white background and no black borders.

Comment: yes mpluth ,as you suggested i changed code with :

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

and removed height & width .
achived same as u , without border.:-) 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you getting a black border this means that the default background is set.

this is how you remove it :

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Try this

Comment: this brings touch problems in some Android versions (such as 5.1.1) where the `TouchInterceptor` is not called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this and let me know..

Be sure to create your Pop-up window referencing your custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <!-- Fill the screen -->
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

        <!-- No backgrounds and No titles , and no Window Floating -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>      

        <!-- Set background what you want-->
        <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Hello Manish , thanks for your reply .i gave my parent layout (pop_up_window_menu_layout.xml)style "style="@style/DialogTheme"" but only background color changed and border is still there.

Comment: i added ur style inside res/style.xml and gave referance to parent layout style. - style "style="@style/DialogTheme""

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are sending context inside popup window constructor.  -

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);
```

> Change this by popup window view -

```
 View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_view, null);
PopupWindow popupWindow = new Pop
```